# XAML StackPanel not updating from code behind

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, stackpanel

I've created a stackpanel in my XAML, now in c# code, I am adding ListBoxes to that stackpanel

onbuttonClicks event in my wp7 app.

So initially 5 items are being successfully added, but on next round (button click) the stackpanel is not updated. Whereas while debugging the stackpanel children count is 10.(using shift+F9), but the XAML is not updated

My c# code is:

```
private void BindAvailableItems(JToken jToken)
        {
            if (jToken.Count() > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < jToken.Count(); i++)
                {
                    ListBoxItem Item = new ListBoxItem();
                    DataTemplate ContentTemplate = Application.Current.Resources["UserAvailableItemsTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
                    Item.ContentTemplate = ContentTemplate;

                    MultiLineItem Content = new MultiLineItem();
                    Content.Line1 = "http://localhost:5141" + jToken[i]["ItemImageUrl"].ToString();

                    Item.Content = Content;

                    stackPnl.Children.Add(Item);   //<---stackPanel

                    stackPnl.UpdateLayout();
                }
            }
```

Comment: After your for loop, can you try to call stackPnl.InvalidateVisual

Comment: @Fabrice : stackPnl.InvalidateVisual() syntax error ! ???

Comment: Argh not available on wp7... sorry

Comment: Why are you adding ListBoxItems directly to a StackPanel instead of using a ListBox and letting it handle populating the panel for you?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem, assuming that there are visualization issues. You are adding `ListBoxItem` instances to a `StackPanel`. While a viable thing to do, I don't see a reason to do it. And apparently because the `StackPanel` control does not have built-in on-touch scroll, you can't see the new elements. Replace the `StackPanel` with a `ListBox`.